# Can Windows read an unpartitioned NTFS volume? (Single large partition)

Tags: linux, windows, kvm-virtualization, lvm, ntfs

So, for various reasons, I've ended up with a 45TB Single Linux Logical volume, without a partition table, formatted as NTFS containing 28TB of data (the Filesystem itself is 28TB).

The filesystem was created in Linux, and is mountable by Linux. The problem comes when I try and mount this within a KVM-based Windows VM on the same box. Windows does not see a 28TB filesystem, but a 1.8TB disk containing a few randomly sized unhelpful partitions.

[image: Disk Management output showing Disk1 with randomly sized partitions]

I presume this is because Windows is trying to read the first few bytes of the real NTFS filesystem data as a partition table.

I can see a few possible solutions to this problem, but can't work out how to actually execute any of them:

- Have Windows read an unpartitioned disk (single volume) as a Filesystem?
- Generate a partition table somehow on this Logical Volume without destroying the data that's held within the filesystem itself?
- Somehow fake a partition table, pointing at the LVM volume and export this to the KVM guest (running in libvirt)

The current "partition table" as reported by parted is:

```
Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/chandos--dh-data: 48.0TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  48.0TB  48.0TB  ntfs
```

Comment: What's the current disk layout? `parted -l /dev/sdx`

Comment: Incredible... I was just going to post an identical question.  I `dd`'d a partition to an image, converted it to a vhd and forgot to include a partition table.

Comment: I've added the parted output

Comment: What's weird is the reported size being 2TB(ish) when it's supposedly a 28TB filesystem, you've sized it beyond the size of underlying disk? The easiest way around it I can think of would be to use ntfs-3g and copy the data out, file by file, to another disk, though you may risk damaging ACLs etc this way.

Comment: @AlexBerry I don't think those sizes are true at all, I think Windows is trying to read the NTFS data itself as an MSDOS partition table, and coming up with just rubbish which it's interpreting as a 2TB disk and a few partitions. The actual volume is a 43GB HP CCISS volume

Comment: What I mean is, regardless of the partition table, windows should be able to read the underlying size of the disk seperately (the figure under "basic").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually not found a good solution to this. Luckily there's another drive shelf handy with ~30TB of space which I can use to migrate to a newly partitioned volume. It'll take a long time but it should work.

There was a suggestion that some clever stuff could be done with the [Linux Device Mapper](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dmsetup) (creating a virtual device which maps a fake GPT partition table from a file, alongside the LVM logical volume), but I'll leave that for someone smarter to work out.

**Edit:** Actually ended up writing up a solution to this [here](http://jiphex.github.io/Linux-Tutorials/2012/11/07/heinous-use-for-device-mapper.html)

Comment: Marked my own solution as accepted, as there's a solution which doesn't involve copying somewhere else and back, however bad it is in the long-term.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where I accidentally imaged a partition rather than a disk.  The images were being copied across the network, and I didn't have time to copy them again.  They were, however, much smaller than 28TB, and I used a process that required a copy of the image to be made.

The initial image was taken by using:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/image.bin
```

To add a partition table, without copying everything across the network, I copied just the MBR to a file.

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/mbr.bin bs=512 count=1
```

Then, I prepended the mbr and copied in the data.

```
fdisk -l /mbr.bin
# take the start position * units in bytes (ex start at 256 * units of 512 bytes = 131072 bytes)
truncate -s (disk size in bytes + number of above) /newfile.bin
dd if=/mbr.bin of=/newfile.bin
dd if=/image.bin of=/newfile.bin oflag=seek_bytes seek=(number from above)
```

Once complete, `/newfile.bin` has the complete partion table + data.

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar, but I imagine @JamesHannah doesn't have a 48TB USB hard drive laying around to store the image on, perhaps the same thing with compression would work though, depending on how much actual data there is.

Comment: This would be the correct solution, given a small enough amount of data.

Comment: I am pleased to see you found an alternate solution.  Even for a small solution, using Device Mapper could prove much faster.  This will certainly end up in my favorites.

Answer (score -1):

disk with morethan 2TB need to use GPT partition table.
for disk <2TB MBR is sufficient.

Comment: Did you read the question? The OPs problem is that he can't easily create any kind of partition table in his environment.